# How Can i transfer the void to textbox? c#

Tags: c#

i want to show answer in textbox please help me need badly

Example:

```
    public void compute1(double n1, double n2, string opr)
    {
        if (opr == "-")
        {
            ans = (n1 - n2);
        }
    }

    private void cmbOperator_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtFirstOperand.Text);
        double var2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtSecondOperand.Text);
        if (cmbOperator.Text == "+" || cmbOperator.Text == "-")
        {
            txtResult.Text = compute1(var1, var2, opr1); //Heres the Error i want to show the answer in the box
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change the method to have a return type of `double` and return `ans`.  Either that your you need to call the method and then do something like `txtRestul.Text = ans.ToString();`.

Comment: Forget about answers, search "Methods in C#" in google and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign something calculated in a method, then that method needs a return type. It should not be void.

```
public string compute1(double n1, double n2, string opr)
{
   var ans = "";
   if (opr == "-")
   {
      ans = (n1 - n2).ToString();
   }
   return ans; 
}

private void cmbOperator_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtFirstOperand.Text);
   double var2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtSecondOperand.Text);

   if (cmbOperator.Text == "+" || cmbOperator.Text == "-")
   {
      txtResult.Text = compute1(var1, var2, opr1); //Heres the Error i want to show the answer in the box
   }
}
```

To assign it to the Text value of a Textbox I would suggest you return it as a string. You can also return it as a double if you want, in that case remove `ToString()` from the code above and set the return value as double.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double compute1(double n1, double n2, string opr)
{
    if (opr == "-")
    {
        return n1 - n2;
    }

    return null
}
```

Usability:

```
     if (cmbOperator.Text == "+" || cmbOperator.Text == "-")
     {
        txtResult.Text = (compute1(var1, var2, opr1)).ToString(); 
     }
```

Changes:

in your `compute1` method, we've changed the `type` from `void` to `double`. This means whenever you call the method and pass it the necessary parameters, ie `compute1(1.22, 4.22, -);`, it will `return` the calculated number as a type `double` We then convert it to type `String` using `Convert.ToString()` so that it's the correct `type` for the textbox.

If the operator isn't a match, the method will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods return type to `double?` (Nullable double) and return the value you calculate. I also added a return `null` as fallback if your if conditions returns `false`

```
public double? compute1(double n1, double n2, string opr)
{
   if (opr == "-")
   {
      return (n1 - n2);
   }
   else if (opr == "+")
   {
      return (n1 + n2);
   }
   return null;  // fallback
}
```

Now when you call, set the result of this method call to the Text property of the textbook after checking whether it is null or not

```
double? result = compute1(var1, var2, opr1);
if(result!=null)
{
  txtResult.Text = result.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Wait, this just always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

First have your function actually return a result:

```
public double compute1(double n1, double n2, string opr)
{
    if (opr == "-")
    {
         return (n1 - n2);
    }
    return 0.0; // or throw an exception?  some other behavior?
}
```

Then you can use that returned value:

```
txtResult.Text = compute1(var1, var2, opr1).ToString();
```